# Is there a way to conditionally override a method in trait that you implement in scala?

Tags: scala

I need to call a different method in the overriding method for a trait depending on the flag provided to jvm command, is that possible in scala?

For example

```
trait MyTrait[Record]{
    def myBuilder: MyBuilder[Record]
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

trait MySecondTrait[Record]
    with MyTrait[Record] {


  protected override val myFlag =
    methodToGetMyFlagFromCommandLine[String]("myflagkey")

  override def myBuilder: MyBuilder[Record] = myMethod() OR myMethod2 depending on flag
}

object MySecondTrait {

    def myMethod() {

    }

    def myMethod2() {

    }
}
```

Comment: jvm commands are provided at run time. Your code is written by you which obviously comes before running it. You can not override things based on a run time value... but you can implement multiple functions and call them by doing something like  `if, else` or `match case` on your command input. This might be possible by using run time reflection or libraries like byte-buddy, but I don't think you want to go to those extreme lenghts for this.

Comment: Just use a `if`?

Comment: Give up on trait and inject an object that will do this op (composition over inheritance), instantiate different class depending on the flags (so `if` in the end).